# decouple plugins list from .zshrc

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-zsh.
I want to decouple plugins list from .zshrc.

For example,currently .zshrc looks like this.

```sh
plugins=(git, node, ...)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

And I want it to be something like this.

```sh
source my-plugins.sh

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Would it be possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Have you tried it?

Comment: `source` just reads commands from its argument and executes them as if they were in the current script.

Comment: @chepner It does not work of course(that's why I posted this). I want "something like that".

Comment: Well, your array is defined incorrectly; that could be part of the problem. Commas don't separate array elements: your array contains the names `git,`, `node,`, etc., not `git`,`node`, ....